# Observe multiple CDI events?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

Is is possible to observe multiple CDI events on one and the same method?

Example (which of course does not work):

```
private void listener(@Observes ChangeEvt1 || @Observes ChangeEvt2) {

}
```

Is there a way to not having create two listener methods which then call the same method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not covered in the spec, sorry. Your best way of doing something like this would be to create the two methods and then have them call a private method or something like that.

I also don't see this ever being supported by a spec either. Any time you have an Observer, any parameters to that method become injection points that the Bean Manager must satisfy. Even if it did work you would get `null` for any of the params so it would be difficult to know which event is actually being fired.

Answer (score 0):

At least on JBoss 7.1.3 this is not possible. I must admit, I checked this for slightly different methode signature: `void listener(@Observes ChangeEvt1, @Observes ChangeEvt2)`. My naive idea was that the container would set the unnecessary parameter to null (practicaly it doesn't make sence). JBoss failed to start with "cannot have more than one event parameter annotated `@Observes`".

But even if your method signature would be valid, you would still need to check which parameter has been passed. This approach would not really simplify this.